# Android XML increases the Garbage collector limit till max size and hangs the environment

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, garbage-collection

I am working on android development. Recently i have also increases ADT Heap Size to 1024. When ever i start working on XML which includes more than 10 TextViews,EditText or other view, Garbage Collector increases till its max limit, and then hangs and slows my Eclipse environment and it will be very difficult for working. For example 1001/1083 ratio in garbage collector. My system config is 4 GB Ram, Core i3 Ultrabook.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `Genymotion`, people said its better than default emulator

Comment: I am not running Emulator. I am running my apps directly on mobile device.

Comment: `Recently i have also increases ADT Heap Size to 1024` What do you mean by that statement then?

Comment: Because before increasing Heap Size it was by default 700 almost , and it took little time to exceed its limit till maximum, thats why i increase heap size. In takes few more minutes to reach  its maximum limit.